# Water the plants

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to solve the following problem:

"You want to water n plants in your garden with a watering can. The plants are arranged in a row and are labeled from 0 to n - 1 from left to right where the ith plant is located at x = i. There is a river at x = -1 that you can refill your watering can at.

Each plant needs a specific amount of water. You will water the plants in the following way:

Water the plants in order from left to right.
After watering the current plant, if you do not have enough water to completely water the next plant, return to the river to fully refill the watering can.
You cannot refill the watering can early.
You are initially at the river (i.e., x = -1). It takes one step to move one unit on the x-axis.

Given a 0-indexed integer array plants of n integers, where plants[i] is the amount of water the ith plant needs, and an integer capacity representing the watering can capacity, return the number of steps needed to water all the plants."

Here is my code, which passes 7 checks but not the following:
plants=[3,2,4,2,1]
capacity=6

Can you please tell me where did I go wrong?

````
def wateringPlants(self, plants: List[int], capacity: int) -> int:
        steps=0;
        for i in range(0,len(plants)):
            if plants[i]<=capacity:
                steps=steps+1;
                capacity=capacity-plants[i];
            else:
                capacity=capacity;
                steps=steps+2*i+1;
                capacity=capacity-plants[i];
        return steps```
````

Comment: You obviously need another variable for the "current amount", different from the "capacity" argument. `capacity=capacity` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Mattheus The problem is that you are changing the capacity of the watering can. You need to use a new variable to keep track of the current amount of water in the can

Comment: @Matteus What exactly is it that you believe the line `capacity=capacity` does?

Comment: @Matteus It would be helpful if you could edit your question to include a link to the [original leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/watering-plants/) for context. For example, that explains why there's a `self` parameter that isn't referenced anywhere else in your quesiton

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you treat `capacity` as if it refers to the current amount of water in the watering can; you actually need a separate variable to keep track of that.

Here's a minimal change to your code that should yield the correct result.

```
def wateringPlants(self, plants: List[int], capacity: int) -> int:
    steps=0;
    amount_water = capacity
    for i in range(0,len(plants)):
        if plants[i]<=amount_water:
            steps=steps+1;
            amount_water = amount_water-plants[i];
        else:
            amount_water = capacity;
            steps = steps+2*i+1;
            amount_water = amount_water - plants[i];
    return steps
```

Here's are 3 refactorings of the above code that I find a bit more reasonable.

Option 1:

```
def wateringPlants(self, plants: List[int], capacity: int) -> int:
    i = steps = 0
    amount_water = capacity
    while i < len(plants):
        if plants[i]<=amount_water:
            steps+=1
            amount_water -= plants[i]
            i+=1
        else:
            amount_water = capacity
            steps += 2*i
    return steps
```

Note: this relies on the fact that `plants[i]` is always less than or equal to `capacity`. Otherwise, this code could result in an infinite loop.

Option 2:

```
def wateringPlants(self, plants: List[int], capacity: int) -> int:
    steps = 0
    amount_water = capacity
    for i in range(len(plants)): 
        if plants[i] > amount_water: 
            steps += 2*i
            amount_water = capacity
        amount_water -= plants[i]
        steps += 1
    return steps
```

Option 3: Instead of adding 1 repeatedly, just add the length of the list.

```
def wateringPlants(self, plants: List[int], capacity: int) -> int:
    extra_steps = 0
    amount_water = capacity
    for i,p in enumerate(plants): 
        if p > amount_water: 
            extra_steps += 2*i
            amount_water = capacity
        amount_water -= p
    return extra_steps + i + 1
```